# jQuery $.get() retrieve while showing native browser loading progress, also HTML5 history issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to have jQuery do an ajax call to retrieve data, but keep the native browser progress bar/tick?

I'm trying to create a similar effect Facebook has - to keep most of the page loaded, and when a user clicks on a link - load the required content and insert with JavaScript (jQuery in my case).

So I made it up to this point and it works, BUT I want the native browser loading progress to kick in, Facebook has somehow managed to keep the browser loading active during the ajax call to retrieve the desired content.

With jQuery I've tried with `async: false`, but it just hangs the windows for a brief period instead of showing the progress of the page load.

Also, a history state question. I push the new loaded page to the history with this `history.pushState(myData,"New Title", newUrl);` and it's fine. I added a `window.onpopstate` function to handle the back/forward buttons and it also works fine. My only problem is some links in my HTML don't specify a page, the link may be just `href="?child=1"` and of course clicking on such a link get's that part appended to the file or link you are currently on. But when navigating through the page with history pushing, clicking on such a link results the "file" part of the new request to be the original page that was loaded first. How do I make sure those links that don't have a specific page or file to be loaded to the CURRENT page as defined by the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Facebook achieves this using iframes, you could use JavaScript to add an iframe to your document and call document.write() to start the loading state and document.close() to stop it from within the iframe

Another option is to change and animate the favicon via JavaScript, there's a [cool demo of this here](http://www.p01.org/releases/DEFENDER_of_the_favicon/)

Comment: What I found out, was when loading into an iframe, you have to reload all JavaScript libraries for that iframe in order for them to work.. Is there a way around this?..

Comment: Do you need those libraries for the iframe? If so, you should be able to use window.parent - so to use jQuery for example, do var $ = window.parent.$;

Comment: And if i need other libraries such as flot etc, I have to manually reinstate them some how?

Comment: You should be able to keep them in your main page and access them with window.parent. For Flot all you should need is to put var $ = window.parent.$; as above at the top of your script and you should be able to use it without reloading the library, since the script is accessing the library from the parent